# How can I programmatically retrieve Facebook Audience Network performance data by hour?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-audience-network

I'm spinning my wheels over here and could use some help.

For our internal app analytics system, I have a script that currently uses the FB App Insights Reporting API to get basic Fb Audience Network ad metric data (requests, impressions, revenue, etc.):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/application/app_insights

It only reports data by day though (even though it misleadingly returns a Timestamp with the response), and we now have a business need to collect this data by hour, so we can accurately generate reports for any time zone.

I came across another part of the Graph API that seems built for this specific reporting purpose, and, according to the documentation, does support hourly granularity:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/adnetworkanalytics

I am moderately familiar/comfortable with FB API security and design, but for the life of me I cannot get anything but an empty data list back from this API edge. Sample request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<user_id>/adnetworkanalytics?since=1467176400&until=1467262800&event_name=fb_ad_network_request&aggregateBy=COUNT&breakdowns[0]=country&breakdowns[1]=placement&breakdowns[2]=app&period=hourly&access_token=<user_token>
```

From what I can tell this means that the 'User' (me, or technically the dummy app I have set up to access Insight API data through) does not have correct permissions to access this data, and indeed when I check my permissions I do not see the associated permission, `read_audience_network_insights` listed.

I have tried to add the permission to the app I am accessing this through by adding the permission through the Graph API Explorer in the dialog that pops up when you select 'Get User Access Token.'  However, even after adding there  I still do not have the associated permission granted, even though it shows in the dialog if I go through the process again:
[image]

I *think* this is because I have to submit this App to FB Review for that specific permission, but when I try that, I do not see the permission available to be selected for review.

**SUMMARY:**

Like my title says, my goal is just to get my FB Audience Network data by hour.  I'm open to any programmatic way of doing this (preferably something I can implement in a python script).  If that means someone helping me get permission and successfully use the adnetworkanalytics edge that is great.  If it is through other means I am not aware of yet, that is great too.  Thank you!